# Find content types for given column

Tags: content-type, spfield

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.listsfieldusedin.aspx

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://”sitecollectionurl”
$column = $web.Fields[“Column Display Name”]
$column.ListsFieldUsedIn()
$allCT = $web.ContentTypes
foreach (SPContentType $ct in $allct)
{
  # Need help here so I can find the field in question
}
```

returns nada. do i need to add

I am trying to delete a field and it said it's in used by some content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a powershell script from: http://netsourcecode.blogspot.com/2011/12/listing-all-content-types-and-fields.html and modified it.

Try this:

```
$columnname = "StartDate"

write-host ("Looking for: " + $columnname)      
$url=  "http://localhost/"  
$site = get-spsite $url         
$web = $site.OpenWeb()      
foreach ($contenttype in $web.ContentTypes) {   
    foreach ($field in $contenttype.Fields) {
        if ($field.get_InternalName() -eq $columnname) {
            write-host("Content Type Name: " + $contenttype.Name + " has field: " + $field.get_InternalName())  
        }   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you Brandon. You rock. (well, rock is hard and senseless). You smooth. LOL

Comment: I changed get_InternalName to get_Title cause the column name was renamed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ListsFieldUsedIn, try to use `$column.UsedInWebContentTypes()`