# Remove site column that's associated with content type in site collection using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, site-column

I want to delete a site column using PowerShell, which is associated with my custom content types that are defined in my SharePoint 2013 site collection.When I removed the content type association  manually, its removed correctly, but the association was not removed completely on the sub sites scope.

Comment: You may to need to clarify - I assume you removed the site column from the content type at the root site level - are you saying this did not remove the column from the content type in sub sites?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a look at this [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40022/find-content-types-for-given-column) you'll find a way to identify all content types which contain your column. Key to remove a column from a content type is to delete the FieldLink:

```
$content.FieldLinks.Delete("YourField");
$content.Update($true);
```

Update($true) will propagate all changes to the list content types (if there are any).

In the end you'll have to execute the linked code for all subsites aswell, before you can delete the site column. Make sure $field.ListsFieldUsedIn() returns empty after all.

Comment: I did this.But I am able to see this column in sub site's site columns section. Forgot to tell that it's a Lookup column

Comment: $ContentTypeName = "Contracts and Agreements"

   $FieldDisplayName = "Operating Location"

$web = Get-SPWeb $rootUrl

# remove Field from Content Type and any derived Content Types

$contentType = $web.ContentTypes[ $ContentTypeName ]

$contentType.FieldLinks.Delete( $web.Fields[ $FieldDisplayName ].Id )

$contentType.Update( $true )

Write-Host "deleted the  content link successfully"

Comment: Removing the column from the content type doesn't delete the column. So have you tried deleting the site column?

Comment: $BULists = @("CBM-SE","CBM-SW","Common") $msitee = Get-SPSite "http://srvr1:123/sites/LAQ/"  $allWebs =  $msitee.AllWebs  # $msitee.split('?')  foreach($singleWeb in $allWebs)    {    foreach ($singleList in $BULists)      {        $mlist = $singleweb.Lists[$singleList]
        $field = $list.Fields[ $FieldDisplayName ]        #$field.AllowDeletion #= $true 
        $field.Sealed = $false $field.Delete( )  $mlist.Update( )        $singleWeb.Dispose( )     }  }

Comment: i have added the code for deleting the  column from the lists also.But this doesn't seem to work

Comment: If you do something like $field = $site.RootWeb.Fields.GetField($FieldDisplayName); $usage = $field.ListsFieldUsedIn(); You can iterate through all the places where the field is still used. Without seeing your environment and the whole script I can't add anything usefull to this anymore.

Comment: Andreas, thanks very much .i have posted another similar question now. I am stuck now, how to delete the site columns from the document library's content type association.